# How to connect laravel project with xampp database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a basic issue in laravel setup.
I have setup laravel 5.5 using php7.0(cli) and for artisan migrate I have install the mysql server on my system (I have already xampp on my system) so now my Laravel project access the mysql cli (not xampp which I access with phpmyadmin) how can I connect my laravel with xampp database.

currently its direct configure with cli php and mysql-server

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You have `.env` file in your project root folder. There you can edit:

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=database_name
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=
```

By default, XAMPP root username is `root`, there is no password and port is 3306.
Obviously, you have to start MySQL in XAMPP control panel.

Comment: I am using same

`
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_product
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD= `

Comment: Did you start MySQL in XAMPP control panel?

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict with port numbers. Try changing MySQL port number in `XAMPP`, and in `.env`. file to 33060.

Comment: I am using ubuntu server I think there is issue with mysql and mysqli because php 7.0 have mysqli only but laravel using mysql drive.

Am I right?

Comment: Laravel is using mysql, not `mysqli`. `mysqli` is not a database driver, it's a library used to connect to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks did you know how can I make mysqli connection in laravel?

Comment: It's not possible to use `mysqli` to connect Laravel with a database. You have to use given options.

Comment: Sorry for bother you. what is other options I have if you know please help me

Comment: If you have installed `XAMPP`, then you should have installed with it MySQL. So, you can change port of MySQL in XAMPP control panel. You can find how here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-the-port-of-a-MySQL-server-in-XAMPP. Then, change `.env` file, to mach the port, and then you shoud be good.

Answer (score 1):

Go to .env file in your project root folder, there you can edit:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testdatagym
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```